# Create azure ad application using powershell but not visible in portal

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-powershell

I am following a link for azure automation.
https://blogs.endjin.com/2016/01/azure-resource-manager-authentication-from-a-powershell-script/

Wrote a simple script as follows in powershell

```
Login-AzureRmAccount

$app = New-AzureRmADApplication –DisplayName "azureatomationadauth" –  HomePage "http://azureadauthhome" –IdentifierUris "http://azureadauthhome" –Password "Aut123"
```

Apparently this was executed successfully and I also got app ID as the output.

Strange this is, I cannot see this application in the azure portal.

I assume it is created under default directory, so checking under the applications tab, it's not visible.

Any idea's where it is?

Answer (score 1):

"New-AzureRmADApplication" has created the application in the "Azure Active Directory" to which your current subscription is associated with. 
In your case, it may be the Default Directory.

Go to Azure Management Portal >> Click Active Directory >> Select the default directory to which your subscription is associated with >> Click "APPLICATIONS">> Filter the applications with "Applications my company owns" >> click the "Tick mark"

Boom!! your application with name "azureatomationadauth" appears.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You are actually looking in the right place by going to the Active Directory page and clicking on Applications. However, you might not be seeing you application since "classic" Azure Portal (manage.windowsazure.com) only shows "Service Principals" in the Applications tab.

In your case, if you're following the steps on that link, run:

```
Login-AzureRmAccount
$app = New-AzureRmADApplication –DisplayName "azureatomationadauth" –  HomePage "http://azureadauthhome" –IdentifierUris "http://azureadauthhome" –Password "Aut123"
```

And go check in the portal, you won't see it since you only created the Application principal but haven't created the Service Principal yet.

Once you follow the next step in that link:

```
New-AzureRmADServicePrincipal –ApplicationId $app.ApplicationId
```

You'll see an entry in your Azure AD Applications page.

You can find more info about Application Principals and Service Principals here:
https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/active-directory-application-objects/

Key points from that article:
Application object: This object represents a definition for your app. You can find a detailed description of its properties in the Application Object section below.

ServicePrincipal object: This object represents an instance of your app in your directory tenant. You can apply policies to ServicePrincipal objects, including assigning permissions to the ServicePrincipal that allow the app to read your tenant’s directory data. Whenever you change your Application object, the changes are also applied to the associated ServicePrincipal object in your tenant.